# Use mean value theorem to show that $\sqrt{x}(1+x)\log(\frac{1+x}{x})-\sqrt{x}<1$

Tags: calculus

How to use mean value theorem to show that $\sqrt{x}(1+x)\log(\frac{1+x}{x})-\sqrt{x}<1$ when $x$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion first you need to find the derivative of this function and find the maximum point( $ f'(x)=0$) 
Then it should be noted that the function tends to $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ if $x\rightarrow \infty$  $ \Rightarrow$
let the maximum point be $x_b$ ($x_b=0.132 $) and in the neighborhood $\epsilon$  of the point $x_b $ we denote the point $x_a$.
And finally when we use this theorem we have a point $x_c$ the point that is between $x_a;x_b$. 
Now direct the point $x_a$ to the point $x_b$, then the tangent to the function at this point will be less than 1. So $f(x_c)=f(x_b)=f(x_a)=0.52<1$

Answer (score 0):

Mean value theorem state that (with appropiate assumptions) there exist $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} = f'(c).$$
Now, we have to find some function $f$ and the interval we want to invoke the mean value theorem. To this end, we need to rewrite the inequality so that there are some substraction of function value at two different points.

Firstly, note that we can write $\ln\frac{1 + x}{x}$ as $\ln (1 +x) - \ln x$, so our function $f$  may be $\ln t$  on the interval $(x,x + 1)$. After trying to do so, our attempt we failed (atleast for me, you do it too so you can feel the fail too).

So we rewrite again the inequality as $$(1 + x)\ln(1 + x) - (1 + x) \ln x - 1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt x}.$$

we notice that $(1 + x)\ln (1 + x)$ is $f(x + 1)$ when $f(t) = t\ln t$, but  we need $x \ln x$. Changing again the inequality we got $$(1 + x)\ln(1 + x) - x\ln x < \frac{1}{\sqrt x} + \ln x + 1.$$

Let's use the MVT for function $f(t) = t \ln t$ on the interval $(x,x + 1)$. We know that there exist $x < c < x+ 1$ such that $$\frac{(1 + x)\ln(1 + x) - x \ln x}{(x + 1) - x} = \ln c + 1 < \ln(x + 1) + 1.$$
That is, we got this $$(1 + x)\ln(1 + x) - x \ln x < \ln(1 + x) + 1.$$

This is not what we want to prove, yet. All we want is the left hand side of above inequality is less than $1/\sqrt x + \ln x + 1$. What if we can prove that $$\ln(1 + x) + 1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt x} + \ln x + 1?$$
If this is true, it will simplify our work and the statement is proven.This is true indeed. I leave this one for you to prove.

Answer (score 0):

**A super artificial proof based on the mean value theorem:** (have no idea why this has to be shown using the mean value theorem...)

First, write equivalently what we need to prove as: For all $x>0$,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}(1+x)\ln(1+x)-x\ln x-\ln x<1+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}.\end{equation}
Fix an arbitrary $x>0$. Using the **mean value theorem** with respect to the function $f(y)=y\ln y$ ($y>0$), picking $x_1=x>0$ and $x_2=x+1$, we see that 
$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{(1+x)\ln(1+x)-x\ln x}{(x+1)-x}=f'(\xi)=1+\ln\xi\,\,\text{ for some }\xi\in (x,x+1),$$
and so
$$(1+x)\ln(1+x)-x\ln x=1+\ln\xi<1+\ln(1+x).$$
Thus, $(1)$ holds if 
$$1+\ln(1+x)-\ln x\le 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt x},$$
or equivalently,
$$\ln\left[1+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right)^2\right]\le\frac{1}{\sqrt x}, \,\,x>0,$$
which is equivalent to
$$\tag{2}\ln(1+t^2)-t\le 0, \,\,t>0.$$
To show $(2)$, consider the function $g(y)\equiv \ln(1+y^2)-y$. Letting $x_1=0$ and $x_2=t>0$, using the **mean value theorem**, one gets
$$\frac{g(x_2)-g(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{\ln(1+t^2)-t}{t}=g'(\eta)=\frac{2\eta}{1+\eta^2}-1=\frac{2}{\eta+\frac{1}{\eta}}-1\,\,\text{ for some }\eta\in (0,t).$$
Using the **Arithmetic-Geometric Inequality**,
$$\eta+\frac 1\eta\ge 2,$$
and so for each $t>0$,
$$\frac{\ln(1+t^2)-t}{t}\le\frac{2}{2}-1=0.$$
Now we are done.